# Отследить пролистывание экрана

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение - читалка, которое выводит на экран (отдельная активность) информацию из текстовых файлов, подтягивая его из raw. Все эти файлы разные по размеру. При открытии каждого файла каждый раз он начинается сначала
Есть задумка реализовать следующее: пользователь читает файл - приложение фиксирует, какая часть экрана пролистана, и пишет соответствующее значение в базу данных SQL, при следующем открытии этого же файла приложение считывает данное значение и открывает читалку на том же месте.
Собственно для реализации этого у меня вопросы:
1. Возможно ли реализовать отслеживание положения читаемого файла (например, по доле пролистанного экрана)? Если да, то как?
2. Как потом "перелистнуть" экран на это место?

Практического решения не нашел

Comment: Проще и практичнее использоватать инт переменную и не усложнять себе жизнь)

Comment: не нашел даже примерных реализаций ((